# How to open shared folder with administrator previleges

Tags: windows, networking

Using windows 7.
I am administrator.

I want to open folder that is share and I am able to Open the folder if I am logged in.

Now if Some user is logged in and I want to open that folder from that user's login, can I open the share folder to which user is not authorize, with my admin login?
Some thing like right click and open with admin.

Comment: Only down notes and no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported mate.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938120

> There are two network shares on a remote server. You use user
> credentials to connect to one of the network shares. Then, you try to
> use different user credentials to connect to the other network share.
> In this scenario, you may receive the following error message: The
> network folder specified is currently mapped using a different user
> name and password. To connect using a different user name and
> password, first disconnect any existing mappings to this network
> share.

Two workarounds are suggested:

> Method 1
>
> Use the IP address of the remote server when you try to connect to the
> network share.
>
> Method 2
>
> Create a different Domain Name System (DNS) alias for the remote
> server, and then use this alias to connect to the network share.
>
> After you use one of these methods, you can use different user
> credentials to connect to the network share. In this situation, the
> computer behaves as if it is connecting to a different server.